# Oracle: select from T1 inner join T2 where date in T3 but no key related with T3

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables,

```
T1 has columns: date, id
T2 has columns: selected_id
T3 has columns: start_date, end_date
```

aiming to create a T4 table.

I want to selec from T1 join T2 on T1.id = T2.selected_id,
where T1.date between T3.start_date and T3.end_date.

So I write as follows:

```
create table T4 as
(select T1.*, T2.* from T1
inner join T2 on T1.id = T2.selected_id
where T1.date between T3.start_date and T3.end_date);
```

However, T3 has no foreign key related with T1 to join on, so it doesn't work.
Are there any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: How rows from T3 table take influence on other rows? How T3 connected with T1 or T2? Or T3 table always has only 1 row?

Comment: Thanks, T3 only have 1 row, T3 has no connection with T1 and T2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that T3 has only 1 row. It is very strange. Just curious can you tell for what purpose have you created it?

To your problem: your query should look like this:

```
create table T4 as
  (
    select T1.*, T2.* 
    from 
      T1 inner join T2 
        on T1.id = T2.selected_id 
      join T3
        on T1.date between T3.start_date and T3.end_date);
```

Comment: yes, thank you. Because a client want to set the selected date period, so that i create a table only have 1 row for him to fill the start_date and end_date.

Comment: I have write it into my DB, and it really works, thank you very much :)

Comment: @QSY please select Evgeniy's answer if it worked for you, thanks!